# How to convert php array to utf8?

Tags: php, arrays, utf

I have an array:

```
require_once ('config.php');
require_once ('php/Db.class.php');
require_once ('php/Top.class.php');

echo "db";

$db = new Db(DB_CUSTOM);
$db->connect();

$res = $db->getResult("select first 1 * from reklamacje");

print_r($res);
```

I want to convert it from windows-1250 to utf-8, because I have chars like �

Best.

Comment: You can use string utf8_encode( string $data ) function.

Comment: What if you originally store/retrieve data in a correct encoding? It makes sense to fix the root of the issue not the consequences

Comment: `$res = array_map('utf8_encode', $res);`.

Comment: @Leri this wont work with a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 48):

```
$utfEncodedArray = array_map("utf8_encode", $inputArray );
```

Does the job and returns a serialized array with numeric keys (not an assoc).

Comment: Works very well for me! :)

Comment: `utf8_encode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`; PHP 7.4.4.

Comment: Just tested it with 7.4.3 - no complaints - are you sure your input array doesn't contain any array elements? This solution is not recursive!

Answer (score 19):

```
array_walk(
    $myArray,
    function (&$entry) {
        $entry = iconv('Windows-1250', 'UTF-8', $entry);
    }
);
```

Comment: looks nice, but what do I give as second parameter when I call it?

Answer (score 17):

In case of a PDO connection, the following might help, but the database should be in UTF-8:

```
//Connect
$db = new PDO(
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database_name;', 'dbuser', 'dbpassword',
    array('charset'=>'utf8')
);
$db->query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
```

Answer (score 16):

There is an easy way

```
array_walk_recursive(
  $array,
  function (&$entry) {
    $entry = mb_convert_encoding(
        $entry,
        'UTF-8',
        'WINDOWS-1250'
    );
  }
);
```

Comment: The 3rd parameter of `mb_convert_encoding()` should be specified otherwise it will take the value of `mbstring.internal_encoding` or `default_charset` (php.ini) which may not be desired encoding.

Answer (score 11):

You can use something like this:

```
<?php
array_walk_recursive(
$array, function (&$value)
{
 $value = htmlspecialchars(html_entity_decode($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
}
);
?>
```

Answer (score 9):

You can send the array to this function:

```
function utf8_converter($array){
    array_walk_recursive($array, function(&$item, $key){
        if(!mb_detect_encoding($item, 'utf-8', true)){
            $item = utf8_encode($item);
        }
    }); 
    return $array;
}
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Previous answer doesn't work for me :(
But it's OK like that :)

```
         $data = json_decode(
              iconv(
                  mb_detect_encoding($data, mb_detect_order(), true),
                  'CP1252',
                  json_encode($data)
                )
              , true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `string utf8_encode( string $data )` function to accomplish what you want. It is for a single string. You can write your own function using which you can convert an array with the help of utf8_encode function.

Comment: Have you checked what's the input encoding used for `utf8_encode`?

Answer (score 0):

Due to this article is a good SEO site, so I suggest to use build-in function "[mb_convert_variables](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-variables.php)" to solve this problem. It works with simple syntax.

`mb_convert_variables('utf-8', 'original encode', array/object)`

Answer (score 0):

A more general function to encode an array is:

```
/**
 * also for multidemensional arrays
 *
 * @param array $array
 * @param string $sourceEncoding
 * @param string $destinationEncoding
 *
 * @return array
 */
function encodeArray(array $array, string $sourceEncoding, string $destinationEncoding = 'UTF-8'): array
{
    if($sourceEncoding === $destinationEncoding){
        return $array;
    }

    array_walk_recursive($array,
        function(&$array) use ($sourceEncoding, $destinationEncoding) {
            $array = mb_convert_encoding($array, $destinationEncoding, $sourceEncoding);
        }
    );

    return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple way tha works is:

`array_map(callable $callback, array $array1, array $... = ?): array`

```
//Example #1 Example of the function array_map()

<?php
function cube($n)
{
    return($n * $n * $n);
}

$a = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
$b = array_map("cube", $a);
print_r($b);
?>
```

The Output of $b is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 8
    [2] => 27
    [3] => 64
    [4] => 125
)
```

For futher details src -> [PHP: array_map - Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-map.php)

Answer (score -3):

Instead of using recursion to deal with multi-dimensional arrays, which can be slow, you can do the following:

```
$res = json_decode(
    json_encode(
        iconv(
            mb_detect_encoding($res, mb_detect_order(), true),
            'UTF-8',
            $res
        )
    ),
    true
);
```

This will convert any character set to UTF8 and also preserve keys in your array. So instead of "lazy" converting each row using `array_walk`, you could do the whole result set in one go.

Comment: mb_detect_encoding() expects parameter 1 to be string, $res is NOT a string.